# How do I pass an object to a Google Datastore function in python?

Tags: python, database, nosql, google-cloud-datastore

I have the following code. I want to pass a museum object with attributes name and location to the `create_booking` function. How can I do this?

I tried things like `create_booking(user, {name, location}, date, arHr, leHr)`:

```
@staticmethod
    def create_booking(user, museum, date, arHr, leHr):
        task = datastore.Entity(DB.client.key("Bookings"))
        if len(DB.get_museum(museum.name)) == 0:
            return "Museum not found", 404
        if DB.get_bookings_number_by_date(museum.name, date)[0] > 10:
            return "To many bookings for this date", 401
        task.update(
            {
                "user": user,
                "museum": {
                    "name": name,
                    "location": location
                },

                "date": date,
                "arriving hour": arHr,
                "leaving hour": leHr
            }
        )
        DB.client.put(task)
```

november update,
this is what I did to fix it:

```
def create_booking(self, user, museum: Dict[str, str], date, arHr, leHr):
    task = datastore.Entity(self.client.key("Bookings"))
    if len(self.get_museum(museumname)) == 0:
        return "Museum not found", 404
    if self.get_bookings_number_by_date(museumname, date)[0] > 10:
        return "To many bookings for this date", 401
    task.update(
        {
            "user": user,
            #you need to get the properties from your dictionar
            "museum": {
                "name": museum['name'],
                "location": museum['location']
            },
            # alternatively
            "museum": museum,
            "date": date,
            "arriving hour": arHr,
            "leaving hour": leHr
        }
    )
    self.client.put(task)
```

Comment: You want to pass these values to datastore right which is Firestore now? Did you try installing SDK and writing to collections?

Comment: Is Datastore same thing as Firestore? I did not install anything, I had to make a group project where a person tried to design the database and none of us knew how to pass an object to the function as an argument when creating a booking.

Comment: Upvoted for effort, someone helped me long before them.

Comment: @Joyce If you feel like any of the below answers could have helped,  then please consider accepting one answer. It will help other community members who might be facing a similar issue by increasing the visibility of the post.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it seems `museum` is not a dictionary (cos you're doing `museum.name`). This means you can't pass it as you have done in your example. You'll have to instantiate it, add the values for the attributes and pass it i.e. something like (assuming Museum is a KIND)

```
museum = Museum (name=<name>, location=<location>)
create_booking(user, museum, date, arHr, leHr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use firestore for your project, which is datastore in google cloud.
If  you already have a Google cloud project, you can use the same project for firestore as well. Please follow the [following tutorial](https://morioh.com/p/ee65b18dda00) about how to create service account and generate key.

Please check the below code sample about how to create the collections, documents and update the fields.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore



# initializations 
cred = credentials.Certificate('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()



#adding first data
doc_ref = db.collection('Museum_booking').document('cust1')

doc_ref.set({

    'name':'Steve',
    'lname':'Smith',
    'location':'Florida',
    'age':24


})



#adding second data
doc_ref = db.collection('Museum_booking').document('cust2')
doc_ref.set({

    'name':'John',
    'lname':'Doe',
    'email':'john@gmail.com',
    'location':'Texas',
    'age':26


})
```